# Metadata Api: "Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element name"

Tags: apex, metadata-api, webservices, metadata, wsdl

I'm trying to build my own metadata wrapper class to call MD-API directly from apex since the `apex-mdapi` solution by Andrew Fawcett on Github is kinda outdated.

I downloaded the current metadata WSDL (API 52.0) and generated an apex class. I slowly added the required metadata types and copied the missing methods from `apex-mdapi`. I had no problem creating the wrapper class for profile and permission set. I can retrieve all information about these two metadata types.

Now my problem: Afterwards I tried to add flow as my next metadata type, but can't get the SOAP to work for me. No matter how many elements I add I always get the same Webcall error:

```
02:59:32.963 (4309745206)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[2551]|System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element name
02:59:32.963 (4310688429)|FATAL_ERROR|System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element name

Class.MetadataServiceYassin.MetadataPort.readMetadata: line 2551, column 1
```

I'm trying to get the flow `PermissionFlow` I prepared on my dev org:

```
List<String> flowApiNamesList = new List<String>();
        flowApiNamesList.add('PermissionFlow');
        List<MetadataServiceYassin.Flow> flows = (List<MetadataServiceYassin.Flow>) service.readMetadata('Flow',  flowApiNamesList).getRecords();
```

I checked all elements of each "complexTypes" in the `metadata.xml` regarding the flow metadata type, but can't locate the source of the error.

Maybe someone here can help me solve this mystery. I created a pastebin for the wrapper class because it wouldn't fit in here: https://pastebin(dot)com/GqDAff1U

Comment: I cannot open the link, it says it's malware

Comment: You don't need to write wrapper again. You can directly invoke same by using Metadata class. Try Metadata.MetadataPort or other aspects which you're trying

Comment: @AlbaRivas I had to replace the actual dot of the URL with (dot) to post the link. Just replace the (dot) with "." and the link should redirect you to the wrapper class on pastebin

Comment: @YsrShk how do I invoke the Metadata class directly to get data about flows? Using Metadata.MetadataPort doesn't exist for me outside my wrapper class